# Special characters in About section on a Microsoft Teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm creating an app for Microsoft Teams from App studio.
In the Developer name there is a special character.

Does anyone have the same issue?

I tried escape characters but none of them worked

Update:
[Image not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/033dc.png)

Comment: What exact error are you facing? Could you please provide more details? and what special character you are using?

Comment: In the Developer name it's written m&m and I see m&amp;m

I don't know how to add images, otherwise I can show you some pics

Comment: Could you please share your manifest JSON?

Comment: Here it is:
Part1:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "00a60dc8-5af2-4251-b719-712d0420f1a4",
  "packageName": "test123",
  "developer": {
    "name": "XXXm&mXXX",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.google.it",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.google.it/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.google.it/terms"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },

Comment: Part 2:
"name": {
    "short": "test123",
    "full": "test123"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "a",
    "full": "test123"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "test123",
      "name": "test123",
      "contentUrl": "https://www.google.it",
      "websiteUrl": "https://www.google.it",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    },
    {
      "entityId": "about",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],

Comment: Part 3:
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "www.google.it"
  ]
}

Comment: The issue is fixed now. We verified the fix in Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.35276. PFB attached screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TMXY.png